# who pays the highest average salary to his employees?

Tags: mysql, sql

Have two tables:

```
Employee

e_id | e_name | m_id | d_id | salary | bonus
  1     Andi     3      B     56000    10000
  2     Sam      4      A     24000
  3     Dave            A     89000    23000
  4     Mike     3      C     62000    15000
  5     Red      1      B     42000
  6     Don      1      C     37000
  7     Bill     4      C     39000
```

and

```
Department

d_id | d_name | mg_id | location
 A       Dep1     3       US
 B       Dep2     1       DE
 C       Dep3     4       RU
```

m_id in Department shows the e_id who is managing the department;
mg_id in Employee show the e_id who is a manager of the corresponding employee.

I find the managers using the following query:

```
SELECT Employee.e_name
  FROM Employee
    INNER JOIN Department
    ON Employee.e_id = Department.mg_id
    AND Employee.d_id = Department.d_id;
```

Question is how to find which manager pays the highest average salary (+ bonus) to his employees?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ...

```
SELECT DeptHead.e_name, average(Employee.salary)
  FROM Department
   INNER JOIN Employee
       ON Employee.d_id = Department.d_id
   INNER JOIN Employee as DeptHead
       ON DeptHead.e_id = Department.mg_id
 GROUP BY DeptHead.e_name
 ORDER BY average (Employee.salary) DESC
  LIMIT 1;
```

This joins the department to the employee table twice, once to get the department head's information, and another to get the employee information.  Because of this, one of those has to be "aliased".  For the employee information, you group by it and use an aggregate function to get the average salary.  By ordering descending, you get the highest first, and by limiting to just the first record, you get only the first = the highest.

Comment: Am no expert in `Mysql`, but not sure why people suggest answers without group by what difference it will make ? Is it just because it works. Will it result the same even after adding `Group by DeptHead.e_name` ?

Comment: @Prdp -  Because people sometimes make oversights :)  thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Agapwlesu thank you for a try. Unfortunatelly, your solution doesn't answer my question, or maybe I just don't understand something... I agree that in this case Employee table should be joined twice, first to choose the name of managers only (there are three of them, if you take a look on the sample data I added - e_id: 1,3,4) and second time is to choose only the employees group by m_id and to use an aggregate function to get the average of total salary = (salary + bonus). Result should show only the name of the one manager whose employees have the highest average salary.

Comment: Right, so my solution gives you the manager's name and the average salary for that manager's department, and it chooses the one that has the highest average salary.  I am not sure why you think it does not answer your question.  The result would be as you say, one manager, whose employees have the highest average salary.  It is possible there might be minor spelling or syntax errors, but generally, this should work.

Comment: @Agapwlesu your query gives the following result: name of the manager and highest average salary in the department including his own. And I needed the name of manager who pays the highest average salary to his employees (manager and his employees can work in different departments, what matters is the m_id in Employee table). But I changed a bit your code and it works now exactly how I needed it to work :) It gives the name of the manager who pays the highest average salary (+bonus) to his employees excluding his own salary (+bonus).
Thank you! :)

Comment: Here is the code: SELECT DeptHead.e_name, avg(Employee.salary + IFNULL(Employee.bonus,0)) FROM Department INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.m_id = Department.mg_id INNER JOIN Employee as DeptHead ON DeptHead.e_id = Department.mg_id GROUP BY DeptHead.e_name ORDER BY avg(Employee.salary+ IFNULL(Employee.bonus,0)) DESC LIMIT 1;

Comment: Yes, I expected you might have to change the query a little.  Without having the layout of your database, it is impossible for me to get the query perfect, just tried to point you in the right direction.  Would appreciate it if you accept the answer.